# HTTP 403 Forbidden on SOAP calls

Tags: 2010, error, authentication, soap

When I do some calls to SOAP services to SharePoint 2010 site (e.g. `CopyIntoItemsLocal` from `Copy.asmx` or `CheckInFile` from `Lists.asmx`) I get `HTTP 403 Forbidden`.

I suspect this is somehow requires specific authentication (like Digest in SharePoint 2013) in addition to standard HTTP credentials passing in response to `HTTP 401`.

Does anyone know how to handle it with pure HTTP calls?
I use WinInet in native C++ application - so no any specific JavaScript libs available

Comment: I should probably use `Authentication.asmx` service but I permanently get `HTTP 500` in response to its `Login` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found root of the problem: I missed `SOAPAction` header. Weird but many other service methods work well without it.
Regarding `CheckOutFile` method, there is some trick with `checkoutToLocal` - I haven't managed to make it work with `checkoutToLocal=true`. Should I first make check out with `checkoutToLocal=false`?.. don't really know